# iphone application for tabbar

Tags: iphone

i would like to use shouldSelectViewController for stop the permission select the tab bar after selected particuler tab bar. so how can i used it. the following code is not working.

```
   - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarControllers 
    shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
    {
        UIViewController *vcnt= [tabBarControllers.selectedViewController];
        if(vcnt==viewController)
        {
            return NO;
        }else
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Your code stops the user selecting whatever view controller is already selected, but that doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want something like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarControllers 
    shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
    {
        if(alreadySelectedSpecificTab)
        {
             if([viewController isEqual:viewControllerNotToAllow])
                  return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```